# Error querying evm rpc endpoint on a node run by Chopsticks

Tags: rpc, evm, moonbeam, acala, chopsticks

I'm trying to run a local node using Chopsticks and connect to it using Metamask, but when I make the request to the [eth-rpc-adapter](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/bodhi.js/tree/master/packages/eth-rpc-adapter), it fails. Here are the steps I followed with the corresponding output:

1. Run Moonbeam node using Chopsticks (it works): `npx @acala-network/chopsticks@latest -c moonbeam`

```sh
[09:42:53.276] INFO (82734): Loading config file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks/master/configs/moonbeam.yml
    app: "chopsticks"
[09:42:55.369] INFO (82734): Moonbeam RPC listening on port 8000
    app: "chopsticks"
```

2. Run the eth-rpc-adapter (it works): `docker run -it --rm -p 8545:8545 acala/eth-rpc-adapter:latest --endpoint ws://172.17.0.1:8000`

```sh
  ------------------------------------------
  ⚡️ running in production (standard) mode ⚡️
  ------------------------------------------

2024-01-23 08:43:24        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: dev_dryRun, dev_newBlock, dev_runBlock, dev_setBlockBuildMode, dev_setHead, dev_setRuntimeLogLevel, dev_setStorage, dev_timeTravel
2024-01-23 08:43:24        API/INIT: moonbeam/2602: Not decorating runtime apis without matching versions: EthereumRuntimeRPCApi/5 (4 known)
2024-01-23 08:43:24        API/INIT: moonbeam/2602: Not decorating unknown runtime apis: 0xa33d43f58731ad84/2, 0xba8173bf23b2e6f8/1
runtime version: 2602

  --------------------------------------------
                SERVER STARTED 
  --------------------------------------------
  version         : bodhi.js/eth-rpc-adapter/2.7.19
  endpoint url    : ws://172.17.0.1:8000
  subquery url    : undefined
  listening to    : 8545
  max blockCache  : 200
  max batchSize   : 50  
  max storageSize : 5000
  safe mode       : false
  local mode      : false
  http only       : false
  verbose         : true
  --------------------------------------------
  
_onNewFinalizedHead task failed, give up 0xb5e9ca22c7a3b49a4249d612684f3841727c64776c149ff9cb78ec952b3236fc TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'evmAddresses')
```

3. Make the request to the node (it fails): `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_chainId", "params":[], "id":2}' http://localhost:8545`

```sh
{"id":2,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":6969,"message":"Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chainId')"}}
```

#### UPDATE:

I made some discoveries by opening an [issue](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/bodhi.js/issues/932) on GitHub:

- running Chopsticks with version **0.9.7** fixes the scenario where a forked Acala network is accessed via eth-rpc-adapter
- eth-rpc-adapter is meant to be used only with Acala node
- it is supposed Moonbeam provides EVM RPC methods, but when I fork a Moobeam node using Chopsticks and try to directly query `eth_chainId` (not through eth-rpc-adapter) I get a different error: `Upgrade Required`. It seems [Moonbeam is not supported](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/bodhi.js/issues/932#issuecomment-1905928975)